# using mongodb with express to get data from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm just starting out with express, node, and MongoDB and I seem to be experiencing a bit of a problem getting data from mongo in node/express.

I have a database called `testdb` with a collection called `tests` and here is the output of `tests`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5395f91ced382cec1f8d70f1"),
    "name" : "CHATEAU DE SAINT COSME",
    "year" : "2009",
    "grapes" : "Grenache / Syrah",
    "country" : "France",
    "region" : "Southern Rhone",
    "description" : "The aromas of fruit and spice...",
    "picture" : "saint_cosme.jpg"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5395f91ced382cec1f8d70f2"),
        "name" : "LAN RIOJA CRIANZA",
        "year" : "2006",
        "grapes" : "Tempranillo",
        "country" : "Spain",
        "region" : "Rioja",
        "description" : "A resurgence of interest in boutique vineyards...",
        "picture" : "lan_rioja.jpg"
}
```

in routes\index.js I have this

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = new mongo.Db('testdb', new mongo.Server('localhost',27017),{auto_reconnect:true,safe:false});
var testData = db.collection('tests');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    testData.find().toArray(function(e,doc){
        if(e){
            throw e;
        }
        console.log(doc);
    });
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' ,docs:"is jade cool?"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

as it stands the toArray callback doesn't seem to get called (console.log is not executed and no error is thrown).
if I place `res.render` in the toArray callback my app hangs in the browser.

since this is my first express app I'm sure I'm making a noob mistake.
I know toArray is async, but it should have been called eventually (and a console log or error should have shown in the terminal)
does anyone know why toArray is not working?

Comment: It appears that you haven't called `db.open(callback)` to actually open the connection.  Regardless, you should be using `MongoClient` instead of `Db` anyway.

Comment: I was following the mongoDB tutorial by andrew burgess from envato specifically the part were he shows how to use mongo in node/express, but for whatever reason mine is failing. in the video he doesn't actually use db.open or mongoclient

Comment: I've tried looking for guides that show using native mongo with node/express, but all the guides i've found use mongo frameworks. can anyone point me to tutorials that use native mongoDB?

Comment: There are Node.js native driver tutorials right in the documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/index.html#tutorials

Comment: that's hilarious. I don't know why I kept missing that link on the drivers overview page. thanks. I guess I'm just wondering why burgess's tutorial is so different than the driver tutorial